# Equations system. Find out how many solutions there are

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have the following equation system with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R^{*}}$

\begin{equation*}
  {
  x+y+z = 1\\
  \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} =1\\
  xy+yz+zx = -4
  }
\end{equation*}

My question is: How many solutions there are?

Comment: Hint: the second equation gives $\,xyz = -4\,$, then you know $\,x+y+z, xy+xz+yz, xyz\,$ so $x,y,z$ are the roots of a certain cubic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dxiv pointed out in his comment above, multiplying the second equation by $xyz$ yields

$yz + xz + xy = xyz $

But from the third equation, we know that the left hand side is $-4$, hence $xyz = -4$

Now consider the cubic polynomial

$f(t) = (t - x)(t - y) (t - z) = t^3 - (x + y + z) t^2 + (xy + xz + yz) t - xyz $

With the given information,

$f(t) = t^3 - t - 4 t + 4 $

which factors into

$ f(t) = t (t^2 - 1) - 4 (t - 1) = (t - 1) ( t^2 + t - 4 ) $

whose roots are to a permutation, $ t = 1, \dfrac{1}{2} (-1 \pm \sqrt{17} ) $

Since $3! = 6 $ there are $6$ solutions.

Comment: $f(t)=t^3-t^2-4t+4$. Am I right?

Comment: Oh yes.  Sorry about the typo. Corrected.